# Algorithm analysis nested if

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am working on figuring out big O notation for algorithms and I was wondering if I have this down correctly.

I am currently analyzing the following code:

```
int expon(int x, int n) /* n > 0 */
{   
  if (n==0) return 1;
  else
  {
    if even(n) return expon(x*x, n/2);
    else
      return expon(x, n-1)*x;
  }
}
```

This is what I have so far:  The first if statement where it checks to see if n = 0 is simply a constant all it gets is c.

The second if statement where the even(n) check is called does this n times, thus receiving an n and the return expon(x*x, n/2) does this n amount of times also receiving an n.  So that if statement is n^2.  The final statement where it handles everything else only executes once, so we can call that c.

Finally we add this all up and we get: c+c(n^2).  And if we want to write this in bigO notation, we would drop the constants and simply write O(n^2).

Could anyone correct me if I am wrong here?  I feel like I am not analyzing this correctly (especially the second if) as well as not adding/multiplying the n's and c's total correctly.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at this in a different way: the runtime of the algorithm is determined by `n`, the value of `x` only influences the value that you get at the end. So let's see what happens to `n`: the value of `n` either goes down by 1 or it gets halved in a recursive call.

If `n` is even then we divide by two and perform the recursive call.

If `n` is odd then we subtract one and then it becomes even again. So for odd numbers we perform one additional call to make the number even.

So we can observe that `n` goes down by one or is halved (alternatingly). That pattern is O(log n). If we double `n` then we'd only need one or two more recursive calls to finish the algorithm, which is what O(log n) expresses. If it were O(n^2) then increasing `n` by one would increase the runtime of the algorithm by a lot more.

Comment: I would say that worst case for total number of iterations are about O(logN + logN) = O(2 * logN), as soon as we're omitting consts from big O - O(logN)

Comment: Thank you so much! @Lashane You cleared things up for me entirely!

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're using looks mostly correct.  However, the order of magnitude is O(log n).  O(n^2) increases by an increasing factor as n increases; this increases by a decreasing factor as n increases.  For example, when n is 2, 4 and 8, the loop is run through 1, 2 and 3 times.

The problem with your implementation is that it needs:

```
else if (n == 1) return x;
```